# Mod Returning Different Outputs When Using Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am getting conflicting results.

With the formula:

> `=MOD(1,1)`

I get `0` as one would expect.

But if I come to that `1` by formula:

> `=MOD((1.2-1)/0.2,1)`

I get `1`.

Even if I split out the formula into its parts:

> `=(1.2-1)/0.2`

and

> `=MOD(B5,1)`

I get `1`

So the question is, "Why the difference?"

[image]

Comment: Interesting. `ROUND`ing seems to fix, i.e. `=MOD(ROUND((1.2-1)/0.2,0),1)`

Comment: Okay, but why `1` why not the decimal part?  I get that it may be a floating point error, but that does not explain the output.  If I take the `Mod(b5,1)` to 20 decimal places it shows `1.00000...` when it should strip the integer.  HMM food for thought.

Comment: I believe Excel has some extra logic to handle floating point issues in the display, separate from the calculation logic. So, even though it's displaying `1.00000...`, when it uses the value in the calculation, it might be using a value of `0.99999...`. Another interesting observation is that `=(1.2-1)/0.2=1` returns `TRUE`. Maybe there's some floating point fuzziness in the `=` operator, that's not used in the `MOD` function?

Comment: And `=Mod((2.2-2)/0.2,1)` gives `8.88178E-16`

Comment: Someone write up floating point error.  I will leave this for others to find.  It makes sense.

Comment: Interesting question. This also seems to be useful -> [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) Quote: `Many combinations of arithmetic operations on floating-point numbers may produce results that appear to be incorrect by very small amounts. For example, the equation =1*(.5-.4-.1) may be evaluated to the quantity (-2.78E-17), or -0.0000000000000000278 instead of 0. This is due to the fact that the IEEE 754 standard requires numbers to be stored in binary format.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examining the Worksheet XML to see how Excel is storing the calculation results internally to 17 decimal digits can shed some light on what is going on with regard to the IEEE specifications and Excel's precision limits.

The bottom line is that the result of `1.2-1` is slightly less than `0.2`; and that numbers slightly less than `1` (at digits past Excel's precision limit) get displayed as `1`

```
A1:  MOD((1.2-1)/0.2,1)  --> 0.99999999999999978

A2:  1.2-1 --> 0.19999999999999996

A3:  A2/0.2 --> 0.99999999999999978

A4:  (1.2-1)/0.2 --> 0.99999999999999978
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of posting an answer... this seems due to floating-point error.

A couple examples/points that corroborate this:

- `ROUND`ing fixes the issue: `=MOD(ROUND((1.2-1)/0.2,0),1)` returns 0.
- A simpler formula, e.g. `=MOD(1*1,1)`, returns 0.
- A slightly more simple formula, e.g. `=MOD(1.2-0.2,1)` returns 0.